# In Angular, how to make sure that $broadcast listener is loaded when a message is broadcast

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, broadcast, angularjs-controller

I have two controllers in my Angular app. When a certain piece of data updates in one, it sends out a $broadcast event, like so:

```
        $scope.updateTableInfo = function (table) {
           $rootScope.$broadcast ("updateTableInfo", table);
        }
```

In the other controller, there is a listener set up that listens for this update:

```
       $rootScope.$on ("updateTableInfo", function (event, table) {
              // do stuff here
       });
```

Unfortunately, it seems that if updateTableInfo() is called right after it's defined in the first controller, the second controller is not yet ready to listen to it, and misses the update. How can I ensure that the controllers can always communicate with each other?

Comment: You're much better off using services to cross-communicate between controllers, especially here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By sharing a service between the controllers you can avoid using `$rootScope` and implement a simple solution to your timing problem.

You'll need to create a very simple service to hold any data/methods you'd like to share between controllers:

```
.factory('SomeService', function(){
  var stuff = {
    thingsToDo: []
  };
  // Other data and methods useful for sharing across controllers here
  return stuff;
});
```

Inject the service into both controllers:

```
.controller('FirstController', function($scope, SomeService) { ... });
.controller('SecondController', function($scope, SomeService) { ... });
```

Create a method in one controller to change the state of the service:

```
$scope.addTask = function(){
   SomeService.thingsToDo.push({task: 'updateTableInfo'});  
};
```

Setup a `$watch` in the other controller, which will run once the controller loads, and then continue to watch for changes in the service:

```
$scope.$watch(function(){ return SomeService.thingsToDo }, function(val){
  angular.forEach(val, function(todo) {
     console.log("Yawn, I guess it's time to:", todo.task);
  });
  // Need to clear in $timeout to avoid infinite digest error
  $timeout(function(){SomeService.thingsToDo = []});
}, true);
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/j0IDYOykAUc9CmjDLI4t?p=preview)

Comment: I think this is the best solution given my problem. Doesn't pollute the root scope, and does what's needed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `updateTableInfo` function immediately, call it with [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout):

```
$scope.updateTableInfo = function (table) {
   $rootScope.$broadcast ("updateTableInfo", table);
};
$timeout(function(){
   $scope.updateTableInfo(someArgumentForTable);
},1);
```

Comment: A reasonable solution. I ended up just putting the table variable in the root scope, and setting up a watch for it in the other controller: that seems to work consistently.

Comment: @allenrabinovich Instead of putting the `table` variable in the rootScope, create service which holds the `table` parameter, and then watch it.It is better than *poluting* the `rootScope`

Comment: Might have gotten a little too cute with the example in my answer, but it does illustrate a shared service w/ `$watch`.

Comment: @allenrabinovich If you've engineered such a solution, can you describe/demonstrate it in an answer and mark it accepted?

Comment: In my experience this hasn't always worked, I had to increase the timeout to above 100ms which seemed very hacky. Still looking for a solution but will probably make yet another shared service.

Comment: I use this solution, but it is brittle: even with a 100 ms wait, sometime the event is still missed in some cases (cold cache? ie. sub-template slow to load?). That's why I search for a more stable solution.